# permanently replace values in a list using Python

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def replace():

    input_list = input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")
    list2 = input_list.split(',')
    list2 = [int(x.strip())for x in list2]

    del list1[-3:]
    list1.insert(0,list2)

    print(list1)
```

for input 12,13,14
this gives as a result [[12,13,14],1,2,3,4,5,6]
Firstly I would like to have a 'flat' list as the result and can't seem to get this right [12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6]. I can get the last value entered as part of the list by removing the square brackets from the list2=[int(x.strip()) for...] statement, gives [14,1,2,3,4,5,6].
My second wish is that I can change the initial list permanently ie [12,13,14,1,2,3,5,6] becomes list1 that is called in the first place. Do I need to save this as a csv file and write to it? I am very new to this, so please forgive me if this is a very simple or stupid batch of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
In [11]: list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [12]: list2 = [12, 13, 14]

In [13]: list1[0:0] = list2

In [14]: list1
Out[14]: [12, 13, 14, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The slice operation changes `list1` in-place, so the variable isn't simply pointing at a new list.  I think that's what you meant by "permanently"?

Comment: I mean that if another user comes along and opens the routine again, it will call the new list1 having erased the staring list1 completely. THank you for your solution peter

Comment: list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] def replace(): list2='' list2 = input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ") list2 = list2.split("'") del list1[-3:] list1[0:0] = list2 return list1 print(list1) using the above, I now get ['12,13,14',1,2,3,4,5,6]. I really am dumb with this. How do I get rid of the ''? Also to explain a little better: for input 12,13,14 , I want returned[12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6]. If the routine is run again, even after being closed, I want if the input is 18,19,20 to get 18,19,20,12,13,14,1,2,3] and so on. Many thanks

Comment: @user1478335 If "after being closed" you mean "the program is run a second time", then yes, you do need to write to a file or database or something.

Comment: @user1478335 Load `list2` just like you were doing in the question, using `[int(x.strip())for x in list2]`